# Largest prime below a given number N

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

This came up as a part of algorithm puzzles:
Given a number $N$, how to find the prime $P$ such that $P<N$ and the difference $N-P$ is minimum.
For small $N$, simple sieves do work, but I'm unable to find solution for large values of $N$.
I tried to modify the sieves to somehow look over large values only, didn't get anywhere.
Any solutions/hints for this?

Comment: Off the top of my head: Let $m$ the product of some initial segment of primes (how many would depend on the size of $N$). For example, $m=2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11\cdot13=30030$. Make an list of all the numbers below $m$ with $\gcd(m,x)=1$. This list can be quickly used to pick non-multiples of the prime factors of $m$ in any segment of numbers. Now start at $N-1$ and move downwards, checking the candidates in turn.

Comment: When you have a candidate, if $N$ is very large use a probabilistic primality test such as Miller–Rabin first, then follow up with a proper proof of primality if that is required.

Comment: This counting down can be painful. If candidates can be enumerated fast, that'll be nice

Comment: Enumerating candidates fast is what the first part was all about.

Comment: what for large N (say $10^{16}$), there the reduced complexity in search space still seems impractical

Answer (score 1):

Start counting downward from $N-1$  After trial division by some small primes, you can use one of a number of [probabilistic tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Probabilistic_tests) like the [Fermat primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test).  If $p$ is prime, $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$.  This can be checked quickly.  If it is true for a few $a$, the chance of $p$ being composite is very small.  If you insist on certainty, you can finish up with one of the deterministic tests.

Comment: This counting down can be painful. If candidates can be enumerated fast, that'll be nice

Comment: @Avogadro:  The trial division can help a lot.  Even $2,3,5$ eliminate all but 8 out of 30.  You can make a list of the moduli that are acceptable and avoid the trial divisions.

Comment: what for large N (say $10^{16}$), there the reduced complexity in search space still seems impractical. (sorry for copy-pasting comments from top again :) )

Comment: @Avogadro:  around $10^{16}$ about one in $37$ numbers is prime, so if you use the $\pmod {30}$ restriction, you should only have to try $10$ on the average.  I don't think that is bad.

Comment: As an aside, if you're used to using primes for public-key cryptography then primes around $10^{16}$ are pitifully small.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen:  But even primes around $10^{160}$ are one in $368$, so you only have to try $100$ or so.

Comment: Indeed. So my suggestion (first comment below the question) is certainly overkill, unless we're looking at much larger numbers still. (But the principle still lets you avoid the trial divisions.)