# Maximum of $\frac{\phi(i)}i$

Tags: totient-function

> For a given $N$, is there an approach to find the maximum $\frac{\phi(i)}i$ ($2\le i\le N$)?
>
> Like for $n=2$, $\frac{\phi(2)}2=\frac12$ is maximum
>
> for $n=3$, $\frac{\phi(3)}3=\frac23$ is maximum
>
> for $n=4$, $\frac{\phi(3)}3=\frac23$ is maximum

From wikipedia's definition :
$\frac{\phi(n)}n = \prod_{p|n}\left (1 - \frac1p\right)$.

So, I guess $p$ should be very big for this approach. 
Still, I can't find a generalised approach. 
Please help.

Comment: What do you mean "maximum": $\,\frac{\phi(3)}{3}=\frac23\,$ , just like that. It's not a maximum but just a value. A maximum can be searched from a set with at least two values, otherwise it is trivial.

Comment: There is a set.The set consists of all phi(i)/i for 2≤i≤n

Comment: Oh, I see...now

Comment: Your guess that $\max\{\frac{\phi(i)}i\mid 2\le i\le n\}$ equals $\frac24=\frac12$ when $n=4$, is wrong. Obviously, $\frac23$ is bigger.

Comment: Oh ya,edited !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $n\ge 2$ be given and $p$ the biggest prime $\le p$.
Then $\frac{\phi(p)}p=1-\frac1p$.
If $2\le i\le n$, then $i$ has $m\ge1$ prime factors $q_k\le p$ ($1\le k\le m$), hence
$$\frac{\phi(i)}i=\prod_{k=1}^m\left(1-\frac1{q_k}\right)\le \left(1-\frac1p\right)^m\le 1-\frac1p.$$
Thus $1-\frac1p$ is indeed the maximum value: If $n\ge2$, then
$$\max\left\{\frac{\phi(i)}i\biggm| 2\le i\le n\right\} =1-\frac1{\max\{p\mid p\le n, p\text{ prime}\}} $$

Comment: So, basically we will get the maximum value everytime for the biggest prime (just less or equal to n)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this ratio will be maximum for the largest prime less than equal to N. Now the question is, how would you compute such prime when N is very large.

Comment: You could see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380440/largest-prime-below-a-given-number-n/380449#380449)