# Euler's totient function maximum value for a range

Tags: prime-numbers, totient-function

For the euler's totient function, we have a number $n<10^{18}$

we have to find the value of $i$ between $2$ and $n$ (both inclusive) such that the value of $\phi(i)/i$ is maximum.

I have have observed that this value will be equal to the largest prime number less than or equal to n. Now since $n$ is upto $10^{18}$, what will be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381053/maximum-of-frac-phiii

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380440/largest-prime-below-a-given-number-n/380449#380449

Comment: Since you already reduced to a question about looking for prime numbers, your title could have said so more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$\phi(p)=p-1$, so now you have to look for largest prime before $10^{18}$

Comment: din't i mention that above already?

Comment: Write a program to find out a largest prime before 10^{18}.

Comment: Even for $i=p^m$, $\phi(i)/i=(p-1)/p$, so need to look for primes and prime powers!

Comment: @AneeshKarthikC: When $i=p^m$, $\phi(i)=p^m(\dfrac{p-1}{p})$, right?

Comment: $\phi(i)/i$ I remarked about

Comment: Very fine. I missed the fact. Btw, is it pretty good in CMI?

Comment: @AneeshKarthikC: The value of $\phi(i)/i$ for $i=p^m$ does not exceed the value for $i=p$, so there is no need to separately test prime powers. Indeed as there are always other primes between $p$ and $p^m$ for $m>1$, a strict prime power will _never_ maximise $\phi(i)/i$ in the range.

Comment: What's pretty good? Number Theory? What exactly do you ask?

Comment: @AneeshKarthikC: I'm asking about the Chennai Math Institute.

Comment: @Marc: I stand corrected.